# execute onChange when a certain condition/event is detected jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

alright.. i have an input box that captures `paste` event and checks if the pasted text/string is a youtube url. if yes, it will forward data to some PHP to process..

the result json data is being displayed here `$('.printdata').append(response);`

**concerns:**

1. what i didn't have in my code, is to recognize if the whole text or
   the youtube link is removed/cut/deleted. it should also remove the
   displayed data.
2. accept the first youtube URL, if multiple youtube URL is found, send the first link to PHP, then ignore the others, just display it as text.

**my workaround**

1. what im thinking (tho not sure) is to put some `onchange()` event
   somewhere to recognize `$("$input")` element is being changed.
2. accept only a single `paste` event and ignore if `paste()` is repeated. -not sure if this is the right approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Pvr4/4/

to test what im trying to explain, input any youtube url in the textfield, and it should display something.

then remove the url, the data remains. OR add another URL consecutively. the resulting data will stack.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     //some regex
$("#input").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var val = undefined;

    //get pasted data
    if(window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) {
        val = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    } else if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData && e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData){
        val = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    }
        //check for youtube URL
        if (youtube.test(val)) {
            var yurl = val.match(youtube)[0];
            $.post("youtubejson.php?url="+ yurl, {
                }, function(response){
                $('.printdata').append(response);
        });     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand your question properly, but i guess your result is stacking and not getting replaced, you can use .html(response) instead of .append(response) to stop stacking.

Comment: never thought about `.html(response)`, so thats what its for.. thanks :). my other question is, how can i check if the pasted data still exists in my input box. if its not, it should delete/remove the `.html(response)`. try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8Pvr4/4/ (paste a youtube link. and then remove it afterwards. the result is still displayed) what i wanted, as soon as the link is removed, it should as well for the displayed content